# Do linear transformations always make enclosed areas still enclosed by their border?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am wondering whether if we have a linear transformation, and consider a continuous region of space enclosed by a border- such as a circle- after the transformation is performed, the border still encloses this region of space (that is, whether the transformation of the border encloses the transformation of the region it originally enclosed when everything is transformed). I am wondering whether this can be deduced from the definition of a linear transformation.

For context, I haven't taken a course in linear algebra but have been watching Linear Algebra videos by Three Blue One Brown, and all of the transformations which he presents seems to have this property, leading me to wonder whether this is true in general.

Comment: Firstly, a linear transformation might shrink dimensions. If we are only talking about invertible transformations, since they are continuous and injective, for a close set the border would not intersect the interior after the transformation and therefore the answer should be yes.

Comment: Yes, one way to do this is to decompose a linear transformation into composition of simpler ones and then prove the claim for elements of this composition. Another one is to note that a linear map is differentiable, in fact, if it's determinant is not zero it is a diffeomorphism. But this could be argued to be an analytic and not linear algebra argument.